# using package siunitx breaks tabular (missing vertical line)

Tags: tables, pdftex, siunitx

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.0cm, right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, ltablex , caption, boldline}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{makecell, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

%\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{test}
  \label{tab:test1}\centering
  \begin{tabularx}{9cm}{|Sl|X|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Notation} & \textbf{Meaning} \\
    \hline
    $U_a  [V] $ & bla \\
    \hline
    $U_a [mA]$ & bla \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This leads to the desired output that looks like the following output:

[image: Tabular as desired]

Now, as soon as I uncomment the line

```
%\usepackage{siunitx}
```

in the MWE, the vertical line in the tabular is gone.

What do I have to change to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cellspace` package provides the class option `column=...` to use a different name instead of the default `S`. This way you avoid the conflict with the `S` column type from siunitx.

(Furthermore, I consider that <del>Carthage must be destroyed</del> professional looking tables should not have vertical lines)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.0cm, right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, ltablex , caption, boldline}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{test}
  \label{tab:test1}\centering
  \begin{tabularx}{9cm}{|Ol|X|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Notation} & \textbf{Meaning} \\
    \hline
    $U_a  [V] $ & bla \\
    \hline
    $U_a [mA]$ & bla \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx! I wonder: since when are vertical lines in tables considered "bad"? I use LaTeX mainly for aesthetic reasons and have to admit that I find tabulars with vertical lines a LOT more readable on the first glimpse which imho is not the case otherwise. Feels like I missed something since until looking trough various other questions I was not aware of the fact that vertical lines have such a bad image xD

Comment: @Junius The problem with vertical lines is that they dilute the information/ink ratio. If you'd like to read up on this, I suggest the documentation of the `booktabs` package as a staring point. For more in-depth information, I suggest "The Visual Display of Quantitative Information" by Edward Tufte (or any other of his design books)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  Depends!  If the column data should be read vertically then a vertical ruler might be preferable. Think logarithm tables, steam tables etc. !

Comment: @yannisl As these are essentially rotated tables, I think the same principle applies - just that the horizontal lines are vertical :)

Comment: Yes. Just don't imprison data into cells. Spreadsheet-like must be destroyed :)

Comment: @yannisl Good slogan!